# Cmd key on Windows

Tags: atom-editor

I use atom editor on Windows.
Atom heavily uses cmd key, which Windows keyboard doesn't have.
Although ctrl key acts as cmd key, I don't want that!
I want ctrl key as is, and other key (like Windows key) to act as cmd key.

Can I make Windows key (or any other key) act as cmd key?

Answer (score 0):

I am not on a windows machine, but it sounds like you need to edit your keymap file. Here is a guide to editing the file: http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/

Alternatively if this proves too difficult, or buggy (i've heard that others have had trouble getting old keybindings to "unset")

you can use the following package, which is intended for mapping non US layout keyboards, but can be used to generate a completely custom keymap on a US layout keyboard as well. https://atom.io/packages/keyboard-localization